# Unable to read files after Jenkins checkout

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have two repositories and one of them, the main one depends on the other repository. I am trying to pull both the repositories from Git and I can see that the Pull was successful(ls in the workspace directory shows my Git repo.)

But Maven is unable to find the files from the repo.

The following is the code I use to pull code and build it.

```
stage('Checkout and compile inner repo') {
        steps {
           // first repository
           checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'inner_repo']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://www,github.com/SpecialOrg/repo.git']]])

           script{
                ['Module a', 'Module b'].each{
                               def cmd = "/path/to/mvn clean install -f inner_repo/${it}/pom.xml"
                               sh cmd
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /jenkins_workspace/inner_repo/Module_a/pom.xml: /jenkins_workspace/inner_repo/Module_a/pom.xml (No such file or directory) @
```

Comment: so you do have the /jenkins_workspace/inner_repo/Module_a/pom.xml locally on the build machine?

Comment: After the job ran in Jenkins, yes. Somehow it didn’t delete the directory.

Comment: Can I see your groovy code, what is {it} variable?
ALso echo cmd variable out, so that you can see everything is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you provide a relative target directory it clones the repo inside that directory. So the path to the pom of a given module relative to the workspace would be,

```
inner_repo/repo/module_A/pom.xml
```

So, your iteration should be changed like below.

```
 ['Module a', 'Module b'].each{
                           def cmd = "/path/to/mvn clean install -f inner_repo/repo/${it}/pom.xml"
                           sh cmd
            }
```